# Getting CAST and CASE together

Tags: sql-server, casting, concatenation, case

I've got a horrible problem query to write

```
SELECT TOP 25
uinv = (CASE 
    WHEN exported = 1 THEN 'Sent To Accounts' 
    WHEN queued = 1 THEN 'Finalised' 
    WHEN reviewed = 1 THEN 'Pro Forma' 
    WHEN started = 1 THEN 'New' 
END)
,
(
    CAST(acc_id AS VARCHAR) + ' / ' + 
    CAST(transactiontype AS VARCHAR) + ' / ' + 
    CAST(reference AS VARCHAR) + ' / '
) 
AS label 
FROM tablename;
```

That works fine, but I need to get the uinv field in the AS label. I've tried all sorts of permutations but I just cannot get it right...

Any help please?

Thanks, Chris

Comment: Could you give a sample of what you want as output? The meaning of "I need to get the uinv field in the AS label" isn't very clear to me.

Comment: Well obviously the label field is a contantination of values, so I want it in there. Its currently:

acc_id / transactiontype / reference

and I want/need:

acc_id / transactiontype / reference / univ

Thanks

Comment: @Chris you also want univ column still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this? :

```
SELECT
    tbl.uinv,
    (
        tbl.uinv+
        CAST(acc_id AS VARCHAR) + ' / ' + 
        CAST(transactiontype AS VARCHAR) + ' / ' + 
        CAST(reference AS VARCHAR) + ' / '
    ) 
    AS label 
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 25
    uinv = (CASE 
        WHEN exported = 1 THEN 'Sent To Accounts' 
        WHEN queued = 1 THEN 'Finalised' 
        WHEN reviewed = 1 THEN 'Pro Forma' 
        WHEN started = 1 THEN 'New' 
    END),
    tablename.acc_id,
    tablename.transactiontype,
    tablename.reference
    FROM tablename
) AS tbl
```

Comment: Exactly it, thanks very much. I was just about to tell you about adding the extra fields into the SELECT but you did it already. Nice one thanks.

Comment: Yes I did see that. I did it a little bit to fast. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want uinv inside *instead* of as a separate column, all you need to do is move the case inside;

```
SELECT TOP 25
(
    CAST(acc_id AS VARCHAR) + ' / ' + 
    CAST(transactiontype AS VARCHAR) + ' / ' + 
    CAST(reference AS VARCHAR) + ' / ' + 
    CASE 
      WHEN exported = 1 THEN 'Sent To Accounts' 
      WHEN queued = 1 THEN 'Finalised' 
      WHEN reviewed = 1 THEN 'Pro Forma' 
      WHEN started = 1 THEN 'New' 
    END
) 
AS label 
FROM tablename;
```

If you want it inside the label *in addition to* being a separate column, you can use a CTE;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *,CASE 
      WHEN exported = 1 THEN 'Sent To Accounts' 
      WHEN queued = 1 THEN 'Finalised' 
      WHEN reviewed = 1 THEN 'Pro Forma' 
      WHEN started = 1 THEN 'New' 
    END uinv
  FROM tablename
)
SELECT uinv,  
    CAST(acc_id AS VARCHAR) + ' / ' + 
    CAST(transactiontype AS VARCHAR) + ' / ' + 
    CAST(reference AS VARCHAR) + ' / ' + 
    uinv
AS label 
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Thanks Joachim, your first example was what I was trying to do, but I was having all sorts of issues with bracket placement. I think it was a red herring. Appreciate the help